# Automating Azure Question for generating infrastructure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to make sure I am taking the right approach.

I am building virtual environments in Azure on a regular anywhere from 3 to 5 servers at a time.  Each server has 1 of 4 different resources (RAM/CPU/...) that it will need.  Obviously I could script out each VM and just use powershell to deploy each individual VM each time.

More over what I want is a utility or webpage where I can say I need to create x servers and here are the specifications for them, how much will it cost and make it start building them.

Is there any tool like this or what would be the best approach to this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates but when you deploy it does not say a cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automatically create Azure resources from a Resource Manager template. You create a template file that deploys the resources and a parameters file that supplies parameter values to the template.

Also, you could easily [edit and deploy the template on the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal#edit-and-deploy-the-template). In this way, you could search **Template**----**Deploy from a custom template**---**Build your own template in the editor**. You could reuse the template after you save it. You could find multiple [guidances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) and [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template) about the template what you want to deploy.

[image]